# Can proguard obfuscate raw filenames

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

If you unzip an apk file you'll find that all the res files are on display. This can cause a vulnerability. Is it possible to get the proguard tool to obfuscate the filenames in order to hide their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard can handle resources files in the following ways:

1. Rename them to follow obfuscated names of corresponding class files (-adaptresourcefilenames),
2. Update obfuscated class names in *text* files (-adaptresourcefilecontents),
3. Otherwise, just copy them.

ProGuard doesn't change file extensions or touch the contents of image files, for instance.

So Thinksteep's interpretation of the ProGuard FAQ is too broad, I'm afraid.

Comment: bummer! well I attempted to reverse engineer a a bit of my compiled apk and proguard seems to have hidden references to files within the code atleast. As long as I give my files some meaningless names before I create the apk then that should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, As per this [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html)

**Does ProGuard handle resource files?
Yes. ProGuard copies all non-class resource files, optionally adapting their names and their contents to the obfuscation that has been applied.**

Here are the options you need to use `-adaptresourcefilenames and/or -adaptresourcefilecontents.`

Comment: so I can obfuscate the contents of files as well as =) impressive. I wonder what an obfuscated png looks like.

Comment: I guess so, I can't concretly say how it looks because I haven't used.

Comment: hmm proguard doesn't seem to have done it. The raw files are all still there in their readable state =/. To be fair I had to change the proguard.bat file in order to get it to work so I'll have to check to see if the thing even ran(somehow). EDIT: Oh wait the dump.txt is there so it must have done. hmm

Comment: oh I think I see the problem. the options you mentioned only seem to cover `**.properties,**.gif,**.jpg` files. bum! oh well

Answer (score -1):

The resources needs to be accessible to the operating system, so it has to be readable.

If you really want to keep it secure, you could consider storing it encrypted as a raw asset, then load it, decrypt it into a ByteStream and pass it into the BitmapFactory. That, of course, has slight performance ramifications and will force you to hand-code a lot of stuff that you could have easily done in XML otherwise.

That all aside, there are many ways to steal data - if it's a drawable, people could just take a screenshot.

Comment: its not the graphics i'm worried about.