# Using ProGuard to obfuscate resource filenames

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard, embedded-resource

I have an application JAR file I would like to obfuscate using ProGuard. It contains a number of PNG files that are referenced using path strings in the application, such as `/my/path/image.png`.

I tried using the `-adaptresourcefilenames **.png` [resource obfuscation option](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#resourcefiles) but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Can ProGuard rename my PNG files somehow? I need it to rename the files and change the strings in class files that reference it.

Comment: Similar question, but didn't help me: [Can proguard obfuscate raw filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297833/can-proguard-obfuscate-raw-filenames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-adaptresourcefilenames` only works for resource files like `mypackage/MyClass.properties` that have a corresponding class file `mypackage/MyClass.class`. If the class name is obfuscated the resource file name is obfuscated along.

ProGuard doesn't obfuscate other file names, since the names are often not specified as a single literal string in the code, making it difficult or impossible to replace them.